# How to remove specific word with xpath

Tags: xpath

I have a piece of code and I can export it with XPath, but I want to remove the specific words from that. this is my sample code

```
<div class="row mg-none">
<h1>Peppercorn Free Photo</h1>
</div>
```

this is my XPath

```
//div[contains(concat (" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " row mg-none ")]/h1
```

this gives me "Peppercorn Free Photo" but I want to remove "Free Photo" and I want to output is exactly "Peppercorn"
and also I have to Xpath 1.0

Answer (score 0):

There are several possiblities achieving the same result:

1. Use `substring-before(...)` with spaces

   ```
   substring-before(//div[contains(concat (" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " row mg-none ")]/h1," ")
   ```
2. Use `substring-before(...)` with "Free Photo"

   ```
   normalize-space(substring-before(//div[contains(concat (" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " row mg-none ")]/h1,"Free Photo"))
   ```
3. Just for the sake of completeness, you could use XPath-2.0 with the `fn:replace` function to replace the string `Free Photo`

   ```
   normalize-space(replace(//div[contains(concat (" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " row mg-none ")]/h1,"Free Photo",""))
   ```

The result in all three cases is

> Peppercorn

---

P.S.:
You can probably reduce your `fn:contains(...)` expression to

```
contains(@class, "row mg-none")
```

instead of

```
contains(concat (" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), " row mg-none ")
```

Comment: Solution n°2 outputs 11 characters instead of 10 (+1 whitespace). Normalizing spaces of the whole expression is required. `normalize-space(substring-before(//div[@class="row mg-none"]/h1,"Free Photo"))`

Comment: Thanks for noticing. Fixed it. Now all three approaches yield exactly the same result (at least with the given sample).